# Injecting AuthenticationMiddleware in Ocelot - how to return 401

Tags: authentication, http-status-code-401, api-gateway, ocelot

I think this question is kind of trivial, but I cannot find an answer to it:

I am using Ocelot as an API Gateway and use my own authentication middleware, since I need to authenticate the users against our own database. The happy path is working just fine. However, if the user cannot authenticate I can only return 500 internal server error, but I have not idea how to make ocelot return a 401.

Can anyone help me? This would be the very basic of what I mean:

```
var authSuccess = authenticate();
if (authSuccess)
{
    await next.Invoke();
} else
{
    // cancel and Return 401
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I looked further into the Repo and I found something that helped me:

```
AuthenticationMiddleware = async (context, next) =>
{
   var authSuccess = authenticate();
   if (authSuccess)
   {
       await next.Invoke();
   } else
   {
      var error = new UnauthenticatedError("Some Message");
      context.Errors.Add(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: I only get the status code, but no body message. I want show the message to client. How to do so?

Comment: Same problem for me, and there is no error property in context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do delow way to

```
await ctx.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("{'error':'Your message'}");
ctx.Errors.Add(new UnauthenticatedError("Your message"));
```